# Horizontal list inside LongListSelector

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate, alignment, longlistselector

Im trying to approach following LongListSelector item:

```
List item text
SubItem 1 SubItem 2 SubItem 3
```

So the list item has one line of text ("List item text") and nested horizontal list (SubItem 1 SubItem 2...).

I have tried to build this using ItemTemplate with data template etc but can not get nested list workin.

My source data is in following format:

```
public class Data
{
    public string title{ get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> SubItems{ get; set; }

}
```

All examples are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `ItemsPanel` to either WP Toolkit's `WrapPanel` or just `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />`

```xml
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubItemTitle}" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

You can see I am using `ListBox` in the inner list because to my knowledge `LongListSelector` doesn't expose that.